# Can I ask questions on "time-barred" topics?

Tags: discussion, meta, etiquette

I'm not in school anymore, but I think a lot about issues that I had in school that never got solved.

If I ask a question here, it feels that it's for the purpose of finding a solution to my problem and a bit... wrong if I ask something about a problem that I can't solve because I'm not in that situation anymore.

What is the consensus on this, can I ask questions about old issues?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Sure. Ask away.

A condition for asking a question here is to make sure it's based on real life situations, and not imaginary "what if" scenarios.

The things that actually happened in the past to you or someone you know, if it relates to the IPS topics, then you can ask here.

Although you may not be able to go back in time and change your decisions, your questions and the relevant answers it gets will surely help others in the future.

It would help us if you add in the question some details such as what are the things you have tried and what results you found. It helps us learn from your experience as well.

It would also help you find some sort of closure if you will. Knowing what choices would've been the best for a situation can help prepare for a similar situation in the future regardless of it being in a different setting.

Comment: Definitely this IMO.  SE sites are not about answering a problem for a specific person.  A greater goal is to provide good resources for someone with that problem in the future.  If you have a good question, it's more beneficial to the site to ask it than to not ask it AFAIK.